# PowerShell ASR Replication Group Name

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-site-recovery

I am trying to use the '*-ReplicationGroupName*' parameter on the '*New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem*' [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.recoveryservices.siterecovery/new-azurermrecoveryservicesasrreplicationprotecteditem?view=azurermps-6.13.0#optional-parameters), however, I am struggling to understand exactly how it should be used...

I am trying to use it with the '*-HyperVToAzure*' switch but I receive the error;

"*Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters*"

Which seems to suggest that the '*-ReplicationGroupName*' parameter can only be used in conjunction with the '*-VMwareToAzure*' switch. Is this correct? Is there any way of using ASR Replication Groups with Hyper-V (or physical) protected items?

Or have I misunderstood the use of this parameter completely and should be looking at something else entirely...?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only for “VMware to Azure” and “Azure to Azure”. There is no replication group construct in “Hyper-V to Azure”.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the reply. Does this mean that it is simply not possible to use multi-VM consistent recovery points with Hyper-V (or physical) infrastructure then or is this achievable via alternative methods? Could the "New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan" cmdlet be used for this for example?

Comment: @jamesmealing, Replication group is only supported for “VMware” and “Physical” servers. It is not supported for Hyper-V VMs.